# Firefox browser not properly opening from terminal

Tags: linux, firefox, browser

I want to open firefox browser from terminal so I typed `firefox` in terminal.
However, I received the following messages and nothing would happen.

```
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead
Running without a11y support!
(firefox:4470): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
```

Maybe for the same reason, `jupyter notebook --browser=firefox` does not work.

By the way, chrome properly opens by typing `google-chrome` in terminal.

What may be the problem? It seems that firefox is installed in the server, but I cannot figure out what is causing the error.

Comment: does anything change adding `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` in /etc/environment  (and then close reopen terminal and launch ff)?